# SSIS Excel Source can't import the Excel File

Tags: excel, visual-studio, ssis

My Excel version: Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.10366.20016)64-bit
I have successfully installed: Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable 64 bit.

Tried to start run Microsoft Visual Studio as an administrator as well. Not work.

My Excel Worksheet are saved as ".xlsx" extension.

In Excel Connection Manager, I have tried use Microsoft Excel 97-2003, 2007-2010, 2013, 2016.
In Property, I have tried to change "Run64BitRuntime" both in True or false.

### Still receiving the error message:

Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager 2'.
Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager 2'

---

The only way it work, is that save a copy of Excel file in 97 - 2003 version, and import Excel Source as Excel 97 - 2003.

I wonder how can I make the current Excel version works with Excel Connection Manager without saving another copy of Excel file in 97 - 2003 version.

So much thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try running it as 32bit.

Right click on your package > properties > Debugging > change Run64BitRuntime to false.

[image]

Comment: Bro, I tried lol. And I mentioned "In Excel Connection Manager, I have tried use Microsoft Excel 97-2003, 2007-2010, 2013, 2016. In Property, I have tried to change "Run64BitRuntime" both in True or false."

Comment: I was mentioning the package, not the connection manager.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I also tried In Property (In package)

Comment: Im having the exact same issue.  Tried flipping the 64bit setting to false, still problem.  Im running VS 2019 with the SSIS project template.  However, Im trying to use Excel files from Office 365.  I notice that the latest version of excel as an option in the connection manager is Excel 2016.  I wonder if using a later version of SSIS would help?

Comment: Also tried saving the Excel files as type Excel 97-2003, but that didnt help

Answer (score 0):

After messing with this for the last 2 days off and on, I finally got around to installing the latest **SSIS project templates for VS 2022**.  That did the trick.  Just opened my project, deleted the old connection manager and recreated it.  Worked!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices